# how to fetch content of custom json output in android

Tags: android, json

I would like to fetch content of this json output ! but I don't know how can I do ?

My output :

```
{ 
  "7916" : { "GoodMainCode" : "7916",
      "amount" : "0",
      "author" : " ",
      "id" : "1168",
      "isbn" : " ",
      "period_print" : "0",
      "price" : "20625",
      "publisher" : "فقيهي مهر",
      "title" : "زيردستي طلقي CLIP BOARD",
      "translator" : " ",
      "year_of_publish" : "0"
    },
  "7989" : { "GoodMainCode" : "7989",
      "amount" : 61,
      "author" : " ",
      "id" : "16827",
      "isbn" : " ",
      "period_print" : "0",
      "price" : "108025",
      "publisher" : "",
      "title" : "يدك اتود5ميل كوه نورB6",
      "translator" : " ",
      "year_of_publish" : "0"
    },
  "8350" : { "GoodMainCode" : "8350",
      "amount" : "0",
      "author" : " ",
      "id" : "1225",
      "isbn" : " ",
      "period_print" : "0",
      "price" : "3375",
      "publisher" : "",
      "title" : "يدك اتودطراحي2ميلJBN",
      "translator" : " ",
      "year_of_publish" : "0"
    }
}
```

I know that I should use `json`/`gson` library, but In my output, `7916`,`7989`,`8350` are extra !

******************* ***updated*** ***************************

Suppose I have an array like this:

```
Array
(
    (
        [0] => A
        [1] => 20
    )
    (
        [0] => B
        [1] => 10
    )
    (
        [0] => G
        [1] => 5
    )
    (
        [0] => A
        [1] => 15
    )
)
```

I would like to remove duplicate values and sum just a row of array: What I want :

```
   Array
    (
        (
            [0] => A
            [1] => 35 // <= sum : 20 + 15
        )    
        (
            [0] => B
            [1] => 10
        )    
        (
            [0] => G
            [1] => 5
        )
    )
```

My code :

```
while($row = $stmt->fetch()){

    $arr = array(
        'GoodMainCode'=>persian_sql_to_php($row['GoodMainCode']), // <= like A in the example
        'title'=> persian_sql_to_php($row['GoodName']),
        'author'=>persian_sql_to_php($row['moalef']),
        'publisher'=>persian_sql_to_php($row['Nasher']),
        'translator'=>persian_sql_to_php($row['Motarjem']),
        'price'=>persian_sql_to_php($row['SellPrice1']),
        'isbn'=>persian_sql_to_php($row['ISBN']),
        'amount'=>persian_sql_to_php($row['Amount']), // <= if GoodMainCode is same key, I must sum it.
        'year_of_publish'=>persian_sql_to_php($row['SaleChap']),
        'period_print'=>persian_sql_to_php($row['NobateChap'])
    );

    array_push($mjson,$arr);
}

//to remove duplicate values and sum amount key values

foreach($mjson as $v){

    if(!isset($result[$v['GoodMainCode']]))
        $result[$v['GoodMainCode']] = $v;
    else
        $result[$v['GoodMainCode']]['amount'] += $v['amount'];
}
```

Comment: Please show your code, and explain whatyou mean by "extra"

Comment: you mean `7916` and others can be changed or what?

Comment: updated my question. 7916 and others can be change !

Comment: so you need to parse in `android` or `php`??  please clarify your question, don't confuse people, cuz I wrote the answer according to you `android` tag...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no meaning of *custom Json*. It is or *Json* or *not Json*.
Given `JSON` has next structure:
[image]

I don't see any reason to apply `GSON`, because given `JSON` is quite simple.
Here is the code which extracts step by step all elements from the tree:

```
JSONObject json = new JSONObject(response); // where *response* is your response from server or whatever where did you get this json
Iterator keys = json.keys();

while(keys.hasNext()) {
    // loop to get the dynamic key
    String currentDynamicKey = (String)keys.next(); // this is your number at N position

    // get the value of the dynamic key
    JSONObject numbersValue = json.getJSONObject(currentDynamicKey);

    //retrieve values same way and do something with it
}
```

If I understood you correctly and you need to parse `JSON` with different numbers all the time, so that will help you.